# Choose Which Mercurial Branches to Push or Pull

Tags: mercurial, push

We just started using Mercurial on a five person team.  We've gone about two weeks and already  our checkin graph looks like an NY city subway map. In an effort to try and simplify things I want my team to only check into a development branch when they've actually finished a feature completely. I thought we could use private branches here but I don't see a way in HgTortoise (or hg command line) to hide local private branches from being pushed. Can you do this?  Likewise, can you selectively choose remote branches when pulling?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-b` (`--branch`) switch to either `push` or `pull`. You can use it multiple time to specify multiple branches, e.g. `hg push -b branch-one -b branch-two`. You can use aliases to specify default set of branches to push/pull, e.g. (in .hg/hgrc)

```
[alias]
push = push -b branch-one -b branch-two
```

Comment: -b also affect **all ancestors** from *another branches* in case of merges

Comment: Thanks @Cat, that will definitely work.  Any recommendations for a solution via TortoiseHg Workbench? I'll try setting an alias for the push command and report back if Tortoise picks that up.